# Why does GSON put a decimal point and a zero after all my JSON numbers which originally do not contain any decimal?

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap, gson

I read the JSON from a web service and converted all the JSON objects to `HashMap<String, String>` using GSON.

I tested and my JSONObject it's fine (no decimal point in any of the numbers), but the map object has the items with all numbers having a decimal point and a zero after that.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("PropertyListings");
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map = (HashMap<String, String>) new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.getString(i), map.getClass());
        listOfProperties.add(map);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia. JSON's basic types are:

> Number — a signed decimal number that may contain a fractional part
>   and may use exponential E notation. JSON does not allow non-numbers
>   like NaN, nor does it make any distinction between integer and
>   floating-point. (Even though JavaScript uses a double-precision
>   floating-point format for all its numeric values, other languages
>   implementing JSON may encode numbers differently)

It makes no distinction between ints and floats. So it's thinking that every number may have a fractional part, so when you're converting a number to a String, it's leaving that part in. Try converting it to an `Integer` instead.

Comment: What about JSONArray.getInt()?

Comment: @Tina, when replying, post code examples so that we can see why it didn't work.

Comment: @Rendall: I just replaced those Strings in my Hashmap with Integer but I saw no change. The main part of the code is in my original q. What other parts of the code u think is needed tell me I will add right away.